# color assignment using the image function

Tags: r, plot

I want specific numbers and specific colors to be associated in plots.

The following code

```
z <- matrix(1:5, 5, 5)
image(z, col=c("red","blue","pink","yellow","black"))
```

produces the plot I want,

[image]

but

```
z[z < 4] <- 4
image(z,col=c("red","blue","pink","yellow","black"))
```

will assign "red" to number 4.

[image]

I want the color assignment to stay the same.

Comment: Not clear to me what you want. Could say more clearly what you want the plot to look like after the `z[z < 4] <- 4` transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

The argument `breaks` indicates breakpoints for the colors and must have one more breakpoint than color and be in increasing order.

```
image(z, col = c("red", "blue", "pink", "yellow", "black"), breaks = 0:5)
```

The code above means to map the values within

- `( 0, 1 ]` to ***red***
- `( 1, 2 ]` to ***blue***
- `( 2, 3 ]` to ***pink***
- `( 3, 4 ]` to ***yellow***
- `( 4, 5 ]` to ***black***

[image]

---

**Solution 2**

Use indices of colors.

```
color <- c("red","blue","pink","yellow","black")
image(z, col = color[z])
```