# how to set color using the value itself as a index to pick up the specific color from a given color vector in R image()?

Tags: r, plot

If I have a matrix sampling from `c(1,2,3)` and I also have a color vector `c("red","green","yellow")`, the same number with factor number, how to use R function `image()` to create a rectangular chart that takes color from the given color vector using the values themselves as indexes?

For example I have the matrix `[1,2,3;3,2,1]`, how to create a rectangular chart with blocks colored with `[red,green,yellow;yellow,green,red]`?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not totally sure how this works but it does. It seems to me that the colors are mapped in order against the sorted values in the data.

```r
m <- matrix(sample(1:3, 25, T), nrow = 5)
pal <- c("red","green","yellow")

image(m, col = pal)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Dan. I tried and found it works. And I found things are getting different if I have more levels of colors than the level of value. Please try `m <- matrix(sample(1:2, 25, T), nrow = 5);pal <- c("red","green","yellow","blue");image(m, col = pal);`. In my workplace only the first and last colors (red and blue) were used for plotting. What goes wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but I'm guessing it tries to interpolate colors to values when they're not the same length. So `1` and `2` are the top and bottom colors.

Comment: I will make more attempts and update the thread if I find the solution. Thanks Dan.

Comment: Hi Dan. I found the solution in this thread [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60897339/color-assignment-using-the-image-function]. It works for me.